# I am trying to replace libcurl from my application with openssl. I am facing issues while uploading file

Tags: c, file-upload, openssl

I have used a sample code from internet and updated it according to my requirement. I tried few ideas to allow me to pass form data as well with the file. The current code I am sharing, has the form data mentioned inside the boundary. Find the code to upload file below:

```
    char url[1024];
    (void)strlcpy(url, upload_url, sizeof(url));
    char *temp;
    char* token1 = strtok_r(url, "/", &temp);
    
    token1 = strtok_r(NULL, "/", &temp);
    const char *host = token1;
    const char *port = "443";  // HTTPS default port

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    
    // Create a socket
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) 
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct hostent *server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not resolve host\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_addr, server->h_length);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));

    // Connect to the server
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("connect");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create an SSL context for TLSv1.2
    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());
    if (!ctx) 
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    // Create an SSL connection
    SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
    if (SSL_connect(ssl) <= 0) 
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the file for reading
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!file) 
    {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate file size
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long content_length = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Construct the HTTPS POST request
    char request[8192];
    char temp_request1[4096];
    time_t time_now;
    time_now = time(NULL);
    snprintf(timestamp, SMALL_STRING_LEN, "%ld", time_now * 1000);
    char *file_basename = basename(filename);
    int32_t snprintf_resp;
    snprintf_resp = snprintf(temp_request1, sizeof(temp_request1),
            "POST /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            // "POST /%s?systemId=%s&uploadId=%s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            "Host:%s\r\n"
            // "Content-Type:application/json\r\n"
            "Content-Type:multipart/form-data;boundary=----XXXX\r\n"
            // "Content-Length: 152\r\n"
            "file_upload_time:%s\r\n"
            "log_type:%s\r\n"
            "log_name:%s\r\n"
            "build_id:%s\r\n"
            "file_created_time:%s\r\n"
            "file_type:COMPRESSED_LOG_FILE\r\n"
            temp, host, timestamp, log_type, 
            file_basename, build_id,
            timestamp);

    char form_data[1024];
    snprintf(form_data, sizeof(form_data),
                "------XXXX\r\n"
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"systemId\"\r\n"
                "%s\r\n"
                "------XXXX\r\n"
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadId\"\r\n"
                "%s\r\n"
                "------XXXX\r\n"
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filetoUpload\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n"                
                // "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
                // "Content-Length: %ld\r\n"
                // "------XXXX--\r\n\r\n"
                ,sysid, uploadid, file_basename);
    snprintf(request, sizeof(request),
                "%s\r\n%s", temp_request1, form_data);
    printf("printing request %s", request);

    // Send the request
    SSL_write(ssl, request, strlen(request));

    

    // SSL_write(ssl, form_data, strlen(form_data));
    // Send the file data in chunks
    printf(" before file SSL_write ");
    char buffer[4096];
    size_t bytes_read;
    while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file)) > 0) {
        SSL_write(ssl, buffer, bytes_read);
    }

    //writing end buffer after file data.
    char end_buf[100];
    snprintf(end_buf, sizeof(end_buf), "------XXXX--");
    printf(" writing end buffer %s ", end_buf);
    SSL_write(ssl, end_buf, strlen(end_buf));


    // Read and process the server's response
    printf(" before response received ");
    char response_buffer[1024];
    int bytes_received;
    while ((bytes_received = SSL_read(ssl, response_buffer, sizeof(response_buffer) - 1)) > 0) {
        response_buffer[bytes_received] = '\0';
        printf("Server Response:\n%s\n", response_buffer);
    }

    // Clean up
    fclose(file);
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    close(sockfd);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    // Clean up OpenSSL
    ERR_free_strings();
    EVP_cleanup();
```

1. I tried using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and added all the form data in the url seperated by &. But the server returned with 202 "Content-Type not found or unsupported"
2. I tried skipping Content-Type parameter, still it gives the same error as above.
3. I tried giving application/json still got Content-Type not found or unsupported error.
4. I tried giving the multipart/form-data, without boundary. It complained about boundary not found.
5. I tried with the current code with multipart/form-data and a boundary set manually as I did not see any function which generates the form-data/boundary in ssl.
6. Now, server gives the below message:

```
  before response received Server Response:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2023 08:59:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 204
Connection: keep-alive
x-amzn-RequestId: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
x-amzn-Remapped-Connection: keep-alive
x-amz-apigw-id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
vary: accept-encoding
x-amzn-Remapped-Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2023 08:59:15 GMT

{"message":"Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly","error_code":"17015"}
Server Response:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2023 08:59:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 122
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to search a lot on stackoverflow/internet but I couldn't find answers on how to pass the form data correctly.
Please help in finding any mistakes or anything I have missed.

**EDIT 1**:- If you are wondering why do I need to replace libcurl, its because the libcurl version we use in our hardware device is very old and it is working slowly i.e. to upload a 100 MB file it takes around 45 minutes. We are not sure what is causing this performance issue. The performance issue is being checked by someone else. I need to find a working alternative.

Comment: "replace libcurl"?  Is this so you can learn how to implement HTTP?  If it's not for you to learn, why?!?! Espcially if this is work-related. Your application worked with libcurl, and now you have to implement and maintain a protocol you don't fully understand.  Your code doesn't get tested like libcurl does, it can't handle things libcurl can.

Comment: You are right @AndrewHenle. This is not a smart decision, I would never prefer anything other than libcurl for this purpose. But, there is a challenge with libcurl we are using, it is old ver 7.77.0 and it is taking 45 mins to upload 100MB file. This is on a hardware device, we are not sure of the exact reason. So, we wanted to find an alternative.

Comment: Also, I have tested the above code with 100MB file on the device and it took 8 mins approx. So we went ahead with this alternative.

Comment: The performance issue is your actual problem.  You should mention that in the question.